# i am trying to autoconnect to bluetooth and return back from bluetooth settings to main activity ?can any one help me?

Tags: android-bluetooth

hello i am trying to autoconnect to bluetooth and return back to main activity,but i am not able to auto connect and return back from current activity to main activty....

Of course if there are more easy ways to do it I would appreciate it very much.

here is code==>

public class SimpleUiActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final String TAG = SimpleUiActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int RESULT_OK = 1;
private static final int RQS_IMAGE = 2;
private static final int RQS_I = 3;
private BluetoothAdapter BA;
private Map<String, Gpio> mGpioMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Button ble;
Button campre;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

    LinearLayout gpioPinsView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gpio_pins);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    PeripheralManagerService pioService = new PeripheralManagerService();

    for (String name : pioService.getGpioList()) {
        View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_gpio, gpioPinsView, false);
        Switch button = (Switch) child.findViewById(R.id.gpio_switch);
        button.setText(name);

        gpioPinsView.addView(button);
        Log.d(TAG, "Added button for GPIO: " + name);

        try {
            final Gpio ledPin = pioService.openGpio(name);
            ledPin.setEdgeTriggerType(Gpio.EDGE_NONE);
            ledPin.setActiveType(Gpio.ACTIVE_HIGH);
            ledPin.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_LOW);

            button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    try {
                        ledPin.setValue(isChecked);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "error toggling gpio:", e);
                        buttonView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                        // reset button to previous state.
                        buttonView.setChecked(!isChecked);
                        buttonView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
                    }
                }
            });

            mGpioMap.put(name, ledPin);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error initializing GPIO: " + name, e);
            // disable button
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }
        //-----------------
        ble=(Button)findViewById(R.id.autobluetooth);
        ble.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                ble.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                        BA.enable();
                        Intent intent=new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
                        Log.i("aaa","i am here");
                       // startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_IMAGE);// Activity is started with requestCode 2
                        finish();

                    }
                }, 10000);

            }


        });
        //-----------------
        //-----------------
        campre=(Button)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
        campre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent1=new Intent(SimpleUiActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent1, RQS_I);// Activity is started with requestCode 3
            }
        });
        //----------------
    }
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
    if(requestCode==RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RQS_IMAGE:

                Log.i("abc", "i am here");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth switched ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
                // textsource.setText(source.toString());
                break;
            case RQS_I:
                break;
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Gpio> entry : mGpioMap.entrySet()) {
        try {
            entry.getValue().close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error closing GPIO " + entry.getKey(), e);
        }
    }
    mGpioMap.clear();
}
```

}